# What does ApartmentState of a thread in .NET Core on Linux platform mean?

Tags: c#, multithreading, com

As far as I understand, the ApartmentState property of a thread in .NET is a COM thing. When threads is managed by the .NET Core runtime on Linux platform, does this property has any meaning? Is it guaranteed that this property is always ApartmentState.Unknown on Linux platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix, [the implementation of the `GetApartmentState` method is](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Threading.Thread/src/System/Threading/Thread.Unix.cs):

```
public ApartmentState GetApartmentState() => ApartmentState.Unknown;
```

So yes, it seems to be guaranteed to be `ApartmentState.Unknown`.